# Getting predicate from Refined

Tags: scala, shapeless, refinement-type, refined

Is it possible to extract the bounds from the predicate/witness of a Refined variable at runtime? Something like the following.

```
// Should return L as a Double
def getLowerBound[L, H](v: Refined[Double, Interval.Closed[L, H]]): Double = ???

val v: Refined[Double, Interval.Closed[0.5, 1.0]] = 0.94
val lowerBound = getLowerBound(v)
lowerBound shouldBe 0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type bound to tell the compiler `L` will be a `Double` and then use the [`ValueOf` **typeclass**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/ValueOf.html) to extract the value of the literal type; like this:

```scala
def getLowerBound[L <: Double, H](v: Refined[Double, Interval.Closed[L, H]])
                                 (implicit ev: ValueOf[L]): Double =
  ev.value
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/zmU4sFEUR9OgFORqDhyYrA)*.